# SQL Shift Table Column Down 1

Tags: sql-server

I have a table of +15 million rows and 36 columns, there are two rows of data for every object to which the table refers. I need to:

Move one Column 0 down one space so that the useful information from that column appears in the row below.

Here is a sample of the data with less columns:

Table name = ekd0310

I want to shift Column 0 down 1

```
Column 0    Column 1    Column 2    Column 3
B02100AA.CZE            
B02100AA.CZF    I   MIGA0027    SUBDIREC.019
B02100AA.CZG            
B02100AA.CZH    I   MIGA0027    SUBDIREC.019
B02100AA.CZI            
B02100AA.CZJ    I   MIGA0027    SUBDIREC.019
B02100AA.CZK            '
```

Comment: There is no concept of inherent _even_ or _odd_ rows. How do you want to order the rows? Why do use such a strange model, it sounds as if you've forgotten to add a details table.

Comment: SQL tables represent unordered sets.  There is no concept of "even" and "odd" rows, unless you have a column that specifies the row number or row ordering.  Also, you should tag the question with the actual database you are using.

Comment: Thanks both - For the even/odd solution I am open to the idea of adding a column of incremental values. To be honest, if it is easier to shift Column 0 down by one instead then I am happy to do that. This is a one off piece of analysis on a beastly set of tables.

Answer (score 1):

THe function that you are looking for is probably `lead()`.  You can use this if you assume that there is a column that specifies the ordering.  An example:

```
select e.*, lead(col) over (order by id) as nextcol
from ekd0310 e;
```

Although this is an ANSI standard function, not all databases support it (yet).  You can do something similar with correlated subqueries.  Similarly, the above returns the information, but it is possible to do this as an update as well.